# Changing a movie clip's contents each time it is restarted

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a movie clip loaded on the stage.

The stage loops through a few clips so this one gets removed and added to the stage again and again by itself. How can I modify the contents of it on each loop iteration?

Can I add some event listener to it (or it's parent, which is...? stage?)

I already tried something like:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, Staged);
```

and the Staged function:

```
private function Staged (e:event):void
{
    trace(e.prototype);
}
```

and the Staged() function gets fired a whole lot, but from it's parameter (the event passed) I can't find out which object it is or anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we are talking about flash IDE you should use `stop()`, `gotoAndPlay(number)` and `gotoAndStop(number)` to navigate btw stages, but if you want to add handler and catch each event of object adding, you should apply `addEventListener` function to each such object you want to handle.

[fyi](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay())

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the ADDED event listener to the MovieClip you want to monitor , not the stage. This way, in the Staged() function , you will be able to reference that specific MovieClip by using the event.target property.

Edit:

Then you should try Eugene's solution. Use gotoAndStop() to move from frame to frame and on the frame have a function that loads your MovieClip with new content.

```
changeMovieClipContent();

function changeMovieClipContent()
{
  //your code here

  //when the new content has been added
  gotoAndStop('nextFrame');
}
```

Comment: I tried that (adding an event listener to the containing movie clip) but it doesn't get fired.

    public function myFlashProject() {

    containingMovieClip.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, theEventHandler);